# Logging not appearing in log file when using nlog

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I am using NLog with .net Core 3.1. I am trying to print out a debug statement in my controller where ILogger is injected like this:

```
public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger) {
                this.logger = logger;
    }

[HttpGet)]
        public ActionResult<List<MyObject>> GetObjects()
        {
            logger.LogDebug("helloworld");
}
```

When I debug the statement runs fine but nothing appears in the log file. Here are other relevant files. Is there something missing or incorrect in the configuration?

Inside program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                })
                .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
```

Inside nlog.config

```
<targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${callsite} -${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\logs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${callsite} -${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>

   <!--rules to map from logger name to target--> 
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="allfile" />        
  </rules>
```

in appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
```

Comment: I'm guessing the missing `<nlog>`-root-elements in your NLog.config is by mistake in copy-paste. But the classic error is forgetting to set "Copy if newer" for your `NLog.config`-file. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Any error details after following the troubleshoot guide?

Comment: Hi @Julian thanks for your reply. Yes, I got the details once I followed the guide.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you should check your appsettings.Development.json. In this file you could have option is:
`"Default": "Information"`

And if you want to recieve `"Debug"` logs you should change this to

`"Default": "Trace"`

in your appsettings.Development.json.